# Cannot perform an interactive login from a non TTY device

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, command-line-interface, ubuntu-18.04

I was working with docker build that was working fine for me but from yesterday i am getting error while trying to login to aws cli docker 
Error `Error: Cannot perform an interactive login from a non TTY device`

Comment: please show the exact command that is giving this error

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the same issue. I was using the AWSCli v1 and once I upgraded to v2, it worked fine!

[Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-cliv2-linux.html) is a page that might help.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I not only needed to install AWS CLI v2 but I also needed to uninstall AWS CLI v1.  Per the documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/getting-started-install.html) that is what is recommended.

"AWS CLI versions 1 and 2 use the same aws command name. If you have both versions installed, your computer uses the first one found in your search path. If you previously installed AWS CLI version 1, we recommend that you do one of the following to use AWS CLI version 2:

Recommended – Uninstall AWS CLI version 1 and use only AWS CLI version 2. For uninstall instructions, determine the method you used to install AWS CLI version 1 and follow the appropriate uninstall instructions for your operating system in Installing, updating, and uninstalling the AWS CLI version 1."